# retrieving an initialized array using JSON, how do i use this array in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have some JSON, and when I use

```
$.getJSON("http://address.com/inquiryservice/getarray/", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

my data looks something like

```
var JavascriptArray = new Array();
    i = 0;
JavascriptArray[i]=\".Other Employer Not in List|.Other Employer Not in List\"; 
i++;
JavascriptArray[i]=\"21st Century Oncology|21st Century Oncology\"; 
i++;
JavascriptArray[i]=\"Accurate Home Care|Accurate Home Care\";
```

how can I get var JavascriptArray to be a var in javascript out of this JSON? I've tried eval and parse with no luck.

thanks

Comment: Instead of returning code - return json and it will "just work".

Comment: I can't, the JSON i'm working with was provided to me and returns code. I'm looking to bring this code from JSON into my project now

Comment: it doesn't seem to be json. if you're really sure you want to run it you can `eval(data)` to tell javascript to interpret the string as code. Just be aware this will allow the third party provider to run _any_ code they want (which is a bad thing)

Comment: It looks like a script, check out [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. my issue was the var that was being declared inside the JSON was also declared outside the JSON. by removing the outside declaration i was able to eval() without it interfering.